# Generate a Query using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, scriptdom

It seems [`ScriptDom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx) has a complex architecture. Since there is no documentation about ScriptDom, do you know how can generate a joined query like this using ScriptDom types?

```
SELECT c.Title as ColumnTitle, t.Title as TableTitle, o.Title as OwnerTitle FROM info.iColumns c 
    JOIN info.iTables t ON c.TableRef = t.Id 
    JOIN info.iOwners o ON t.OwnerRef = o.Id 
    JOIN info.iTablesKey k ON k.TableRef = t.Id
    WHERE t.DisplayIndex = 1
```

I want to create a simple query generator for my report builder and I don't know how to build `JOIN` statements. I have checked [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2013/10/30/xml-visualizer-for-the-transactsql-scriptdom-parse-tree.aspx) but the generated xml for object graph is very complex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out what you need to add is to do the reverse - start with your t-sql, use the parser to parse it and create a TSqlScript which you then pass to a class that implements TSqlFragmentVisitor.

In your class that implements TSqlFragmentVisitor do an override on Visit(TSqlScript node) - put a breakpoint in there and then you can explore what objects make up your query.

Building an AST using the ScriptDom is quite challenging but rewarding in the end :)

For example on how to use the scriptdom see the scriptdom section of this:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/DacFx-Create-tSQLt-Tests-From-A-Dacpac

I don't have an exact example of your use case to hand.